# How can I connect a faucet adapter to a non-standard faucet without leaks?

Tags: leak, faucet, dishwasher

I have a brand new countertop dishwasher with a faucet adapter that connects the faucet with a hose going into the dishwasher. Both my faucet and the faucet adapter are double threaded (inside and outside) but the sizes of the threads on my faucet are not compatible.

I have gone to Home Depot and tried various size adapters, which seem to come in the sizes 3/4,55/64, and 15/16 inch (increasing order). My sink is between a 55/64 and a 15/16, and the faucet adapter is 15/16 inch.

So given that a direct fit isn't possible, what is the best way to make the connection? I have tried thread seal tape  but I can't get a fit tight enough. Will super glue help, or is there something better to make the connection? (I'll need to remove the adapter when I move out.)

Comment: Sounds like your sink tap's thread is metric, actually.

Answer (score 1):

Take the aerator from your faucet and the adapter from your dishwasher to a plumbing supply store. They will have a bigger selection of sizes. It is possible you have an unusual faucet that HomeDepot doesn't carry. Do not use superglue. If you do anything to alter the fixture you could be responsible for replaceing it when you leave.